# c programming , matrix addition , weird flaw

Tags: c

[image]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(){
    int r1,c1,r2,c2,sum;
     printf("Enter the number of rows and colums for first matrix ");
     scanf ("%d ,%d",&r1,&c1);
     
    int a[r1][c1];
    int b [r2][c2];
    int i,j,k;
     
    
     for(i=0;i<r1;i++){
        
        for(j=0;j<c1;j++){
            k=((i+1)*10)+(j+1);
            printf("enter element [a %d ] = ",k);
            scanf("%D",&a[i][j]);
         }
         }


printf("the first matrix is : \n");
printf("\t");
for(i=0;i<r1;i++){
    for(j=0;j<c1;j++){
    printf("%d ",a[i][j]);  
    }
    printf("\n \t");
}
printf("\n") ;
printf("Enter the number of rows and colums for second matrix ");
     scanf ("%d ,%d",&r2,&c2);
     if (r1!=r2 || c1!=c2){
        printf("Only matrices of similar orders can be added or subtracted ");
        }
         else{
         
     
 for(i=0;i<r2;i++){
        
        for(j=0;j<c2;j++){
            k=((i+1)*10)+(j+1);
            printf("enter element [a %d ] = ",k);
            scanf("%d",&b[i][j]);
         }
         
         }
         
printf("the second matrix is : \n");
printf("\t");
for(i=0;i<r1;i++){
    for(j=0;j<c1;j++){
    printf("%d ",b[i][j]);  
    }
    printf("\n \t");
}
        printf("\n the added matrix is \n \t");
         for(i=0;i<r1;i++){
    for(j=0;j<c1;j++){
    printf("%d ",a[i][j]+b[i][j]);  
    }
    printf("\n \t");
} 
         
    }
}
```

as you can see the first matrix is display correctly but the second one is faulty , i don't know where i went wrong because i used the same logic for both please help.
the 2nd matrix seems faulty and i cant figure out why ? i repeated the same process i did for matrix 1 but it doesn't want to work.

Comment: When you define the array `b`, what are the values of `r2` and `c2`?

Comment: Please don't show pictures of text. Show the text itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int main(){
    int r1,c1,r2,c2,sum;
     printf("Enter the number of rows and colums for first matrix ");
     scanf ("%d ,%d",&r1,&c1);
     
    int a[r1][c1];
    int b [r2][c2];
```

Question: what are the values of `r2` and `c2` at the last line?
Answer: they are undefined, so *anything* can happen.

Comment: thanks i got it  i just need to change r2 to r1 and c2 to c1 as they are like matrices or declare the second matrix only after the first matrix is printed

Comment: @AàrohanYT If the answer addressed your question, please accept it.